# Why are these text files opening as strings?

Tags: python

I have two .txt files which I pass as command line argument to a program. I want to read the entirety, without the first line.

```
patterns = ["".join(sys.argv[1].readlines()[1:])]
text = "".join(sys.argv[2].readlines()[1:])
```

This returns this error:

```
File "trie_builder.py", line 186, in main
    patterns = ["".join(sys.argv[1].readlines()[1:])]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

How can sys.arg[1] be a string if I passed the file 'xx.txt' to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifying file **names** as the command's arguments but you're not opening them.

Use the built-in [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

```
f1 = open(sys.argv[1])
# f1.readlines()...
```

And:

```
f2 = open(sys.argv[2])
# f2.readlines()...
```

Or even better:

```
with f as open(sys.argv[1]):
    # f.readlines()...
```

Currently you're treating the file name as a file, it's not.

And try to avoid big one-liners, they are hard to maintain and modify... :-)

Answer (score 2):

To open a file in python you need to use the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function. Currently you are trying to use `readlines` on a string object which is what the `argv` variables are.

Your code should do something similar to the following:

```
def readlines( f ):
    lines = [ line for line in open( f ) ]
    return lines

patterns = "".join( readlines( sys.argv[1] )[1:] )
text = "".join( readlines( sys.argv[2] )[1:] )
```

I took the `[]` Brackets off the pattern line since I don't think you meant to put the `patterns` file as a 1 element list containing the file contents, but you may have.